# How to measure the size of int and short variable by memory allocating features?

Tags: c, compiler-construction, x86-64

I tried to test the length of `int` and `short` type in my computer (X86_64), so I wrote two pieces of codes as bellow:
short:

```
short a;
scanf("%hd%hd",&a,&a+1);
printf("%hd",a+*(&a+1));
```

int:

```
int a;
scanf("%d%d",&a,&a+1);
printf("%d",a+*(&a+1));
```

Both work and output the right answer, but when I change to number `1` to `4`, the first one works well while the second one show a `Segmentation fault` after input.
Some materials say that the lengths of short and int are all 16 bits in  x86, I don't know the difference in x86_64, are they the same? 
In addition, what caused the `Segmentation fault`?

PS:I use `gcc -Wall -O2 -o filename -lm` to compile.

Comment: Why would you think that the code above would help you determine the size of any type?

Comment: You can use the `sizeof` expression to determine the size of a type. `printf("%d\n", (int) sizeof(short));`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have known what's wrong with my code after reading your comments and answers.
I guessed the address of a variable is like that in assembly language, so if I get an address and add it with the length of a variable I can get the address of the following viable.  I use `&a+4` first to test if the length of `int` is `4 BYTES`, but there was a `Segmentation fault` while running, I changed `4` to `1` and get the correct value, I didn't understand why this worked? Now, I got it.
In the following code:

```
short a,b;
a = b = 1024;
cout << &a << endl << &b << endl;
cout << &a << endl << (&a) + 1;
```

An output of it is:

```
0xbfad153c  
0xbfad153e  
0xbfad153c  
0xbfad153e
```

And

```
int a,b;
a = b = 1024;
cout << &a << endl << &b << endl;
cout << &a << endl << (&a) + 1;
return 0;
```

An Output is:

```
0xbfddb968  
0xbfddb96c  
0xbfddb968  
0xbfddb96c
```

It shows that `&a + 1` here plus the value of the size of `int a` but not the `literal const value` of `1`
So I just want to use the feature of memory allocating to measure the size of `int` and `short`, not `sizeof` function.
Thanks for your answers and comments, even though they are not what I want to get.

Comment: Which variable is *the following variable*? Depends on Compiler, Compiler flags, exact sources and your exact situation when you compiled it (it is unstable). Also, you don't do *address arithmetic* in C++, you do *pointer arithmetic*, meaning there's auto-scaling for the pointer type in question built-in.

Answer (score 3):

All x86 ABIs define `sizeof(short) == 2`.
All x86 16-Bit ABIs define `sizeof(int) == 2`, all other x86 ABIs define `sizeof(int) == 4`.
For standard 64Bit mode, every pointer is 64Bit == 8 Byte big, for 64Bit 4G-Address mode and for 32Bit flat memory mode (flat is standard), every pointer is 32Bit == 4 Byte, and for 16Bit mode it varies.

This example has **Undefined Behavior**, because you do not own a `short`-object at `&a+1`:

```
short a;
scanf("%hd%hd",&a,&a+1);
printf("%hd",a+*(&a+1));
```

Same for this one, just with `int`:

```
int a;
scanf("%d%d",&a,&a+1);
printf("%d",a+*(&a+1));
```

**Undefined Behavior** means anything may happen, even the proverbial nasal demons.
That includes *it seems to work* as well as *reformatted your drive*.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the size of `short` by:

```
printf("size of short: %d\n", sizeof(short));
```

You can get the size of `short` pointer, by:

```
printf("size of pointr: %d\n", sizeof(short*));
```

I believe your other questions have been answered by Deduplicator.

Comment: `sizeof(void *)` may differ from `sizeof(other_type *)`. On modern systems they are the same as that is the most convenient way to do it when you don't have a limited address space; but that hasn't always been so.

Comment: @MattMcNabb I feel like you are always there to broaden my knowledge of C++. Some times it's annoying. Most of the time it's educative. Do you have a reference to this bit of nugget?

Comment: In `[basic.compound]` in the Standard, "The value representation of pointer types is implementation-defined". The term *value representation* is defined in the previous section as "the set of bits that hold the value of type T"; when we're talking about pointers that is the set of bits holding the pointer, not the thing pointed-to. A couple of cases are given where pointers to two particular types must have the same rep and alignment, but there's no general clause that all pointers have the same rep and alignment.

Comment: @MattMcNabb Another thing I learned from you. Thank you. BTW, I just updated my answer to reflect my new understanding.

Comment: `%d` requires an `int` argument; `sizeof` yields a `size_t`. Either car the argument to `int` or use `%zu` (if your implementation supports it; Microsoft's may not).